# Pass awk command "results" as variable to date command

Tags: bash, date, awk

I have a file with the following two columns in it:

```
"2014-07-22 17:45:00"   1406051695440
"2014-07-23 09:00:00"   1406138960913
"2014-07-23 09:00:00"   1406185159123
"2014-07-23 12:00:00"   1406142510435
"2014-07-24 10:23:00"   1406232985082
"2014-07-24 12:00:00"   1406206824292
"2014-07-24 13:30:00"   1406217480193
"2014-07-25 07:53:28"   1406275797916
"2014-07-29 10:30:00"   1406652173807
"2014-07-29 13:30:00"   1406659544903
"2014-07-30 09:00:00"   1406727826714
"2014-07-30 12:00:00"   1406745888737
"2014-07-30 12:59:27"   1406725794340
"2014-07-31 12:00:00"   1406829925055
"2014-07-31 13:30:00"   1406834428886
"2014-08-01 09:00:00"   1406897311292
"2014-08-04 09:33:06"   1407145793582
"2014-08-04 10:27:09"   1407149395816
"2014-08-05 13:30:00"   1407282683770
"2014-08-06 09:00:00"   1407344800476
"2014-08-06 12:00:00"   1407375490735
"2014-08-06 13:27:00"   1407371123661
"2014-08-07 12:00:00"   1407505272918
"2014-08-07 13:30:00"   1407870069228
"2014-08-08 08:58:00"   1407518580468
"2014-08-08 09:53:48"   1407492483505
"2014-08-20 07:10:00"   1408552070009
"2014-08-21 06:51:00"   1408604587871
"2014-08-21 07:33:00"   1408607299171
"2014-08-21 08:20:00"   1408693609065
"2014-08-21 12:00:00"   1408734166746
"2014-08-21 12:25:00"   1408972414360
"2014-08-21 13:30:00"   1408670893024
"2014-08-22 06:00:00"   1408725813939
"2014-08-22 08:00:00"   1408975254694
"2014-08-22 08:58:00"   1408733752599
"2014-08-22 10:05:00"   1408718965157
"2014-08-22 11:00:00"   1408731612398
"2014-08-22 13:30:00"   1408752932528
"2014-08-25 06:15:00"   1408983576002
"2014-08-25 08:15:00"   1408984680142
"2014-08-25 09:50:00"   1409068894755
"2014-08-25 12:00:00"   1408999355264
"2014-08-26 06:45:32"   1409036603781
"2014-08-26 06:49:23"   1409036887123
"2014-08-26 10:30:00"   1409066332536
"2014-08-26 13:30:00"   1409105945904
```

What I am trying to do is to get the date-time value converted, so that I can perform arithmetic on it.

As you all will know the format of the date command is:

```
date -u -d "2014-07-22 17:45:00" +%s
```

So what I have done so far is to get the command going to extract the first column exactly as it is:

```
awk  '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' times.txt
```

There are two things I am struggling with:

1) Getting the result from the `awk` command passed to the `date` command.  Something like this:

```
awk  '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' times.txt | date -u -d AWK_RESULT_HERE +%s
```

2) Isn't there a way to do the conversion in place, so that when all the dates in the file have been converted, that I can do the arithmetic on it?

Column two is an end value in milliseconds since epoch, and I still need to find a way to convert that in place as well, although I think I can get that to work.
Column one is the start time. So I want the time elapsed for each line (end time - start time).

Thanks in advance for all the help!  I really appreciate all the answers I get on this forum!

Comment: You could use a while loop: `awk  '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' times.txt | while read LINE; do date -u -d $LINE +%s; done`

Comment: @scragar That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @scragar Thanks for the quick reply, although, I get an error stating: `date: extra operand +%s` and when I change it to `awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' times.txt | while read LINE; do date -u -d "$LINE" +%s; done` I get `date: invalid date `"2014-09-10 07:00:00"'  ` Please note the sign befor "2014" is an expression sign and the one at the end is single quotation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU awk has builtin time functions so you can do this:

```
gawk -F '"' '
    function datetime2epoch(dt) {
        gsub(/[-:]/, " ", dt)
        return mktime(dt)
    }
    {
        t1 = datetime2epoch($2) 
        t2 = $3/1000
        printf "%10d  %14.3f  %.3f\n", t1, t2, t2-t1
    }
' time.data
```

```
1406065500  1406051695.440  -13804.560
1406120400  1406138960.913  18560.913
1406120400  1406185159.123  64759.123
1406131200  1406142510.435  11310.435
...
```